# "messages status" div not showing up when submitting page comment

Tags: 6, comments, status-messages

"messages status" div not showing up when submitting page comment.

It's just a regular old page content type and "messages error" div shows up fine in same place... when I try to submit a comment and leave something blank.

But, if I fill everything in, then the comment goes through and shows-up, but it doesn't get me the expected "messages status" div (the div tag doesn't show-up there at all.)

After successfully submitting a comment, it goes to a URL something like this:
http://mywebsite.com/pages/2013/april#comment-4563

page.tpl.php - Looks good:  `<?php print $messages ?>`

It should say something similar to what another Drupal 6 site of my says:

> Your comment has been queued for review by site administrators and
>   will be published after approval.

Someone else set the site up, so I have no idea when it stopped working... I'm going thru opening permissions and disabling various modules...

Does anyone have any clues or answers on why this would happen?

Any help, would be greatly appreciated... Thanks in advance!

Comment: clear cache and try again ?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the following permissions:

[image]

to see what is going on.  On first blush, I'm going to assume `post comments without approval` is checked for more roles than you want or expect.

You can also surf over to `admin/content/node-type/CONTENT-TYPE` and click on "Comment settings" to see if anything is set for that specific type of node.

If these don't give you any "AHA!" moments, look around to see if any other comment approval modules are in place on the system.

Also, a lot of page.tpl's in D6 wrap their various content areas with something like this:

```
<?php if ($messages): ?>
  <div id="messages">
    <?php print $messages; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

which basically means if you don't have any content for that area, there is no need to print an empty `<div>` which probably explains why you aren't seeing anything (eg, there was no message in the first place).

Comment: Thanks for your help... but... still no clue...

- I have ALL the permissions turned-on now for every role, just to see. (but I don't get the messages status div for user1 either, so...)

- page.tpl.php - has exactly this: <?php print $messages ?>

- I looked at admin/content/node-type/CONTENT-TYPE... it all looks normal and just like you'd expect on every other one of my sites.

I will look around and keep disabling modules...

Please let me know if you think of anything else, or if anyone else has any bright ideas.

Thanks again!